# What does 懐{なつ}い mean in this context?

Tags: translation, slang

Saw this on twitter:

> A: 懐い
>
> B: そういえば私がマオさんの唄初めて聞いたのwinter fallでした。サンタさんでしたね（笑）あの日の衝撃は未だに忘れられないなー「歌うますぎ！この人誰！？」ってみんな言ってましたよ。懐かしい。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`懐い` is a slang for `懐かしい`. It is a kind of nostalgia/sentimental feeling that occurs when you remember the past or encounter something that reminds you of the past.